# Can't set net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1 sysctl parameter

Tags: 14.04, networking

I've been working with AWS to diagnose an issue I've been having whereby my collectd installation stops pushing metrics invariably after a reboot, and subsequent service/instance reboots don't fix it, without a change in networking - it appears, for all intents and purposes, that the traffic is just being blackholed. The support person suggested I run the following to adjust the arp table caching:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1=0
```

However, I am unable to set this value, and get the following error when I try to set it to 0 or indeed any value (16, 32, 4096, etc):

```
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1": Invalid argument
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1 = 0
```

It seems like this may be a bug for everyone using Ubuntu 14.04, but does anyone have any further insight as to the cause? I upgraded to 3.13.103 today after seeing below that a fix may have been committed, but a fix does not seem present. Is there any way to step around this on 14.04 for the time being? I've tried manually setting the value in /etc/sysctl.conf and running sysctl -p to no avail.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-trusty/+bug/1634892